# Unable to show 2 graphs with grid on in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, grid

I am making a GUI in Matlab. This is a sample of my code

```
function plotResults(handles)

% Create output data plot in proper axes
plot(handles.outputAxes, handles.outputCurrentData, handles.outputVoltageData,'.-')
set(handles.outputAxes, 'XMinorTick', 'on')
grid on

% Create magnet data plot in proper axes
plot(handles.magnetAxes, handles.magnetCurrentData, handles.magnetVoltageData, '.-')
set(handles.magnetAxes, 'XMinorTick', 'on')
grid on
```

However, only the 2nd axis displays a grid, the first does not. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is peculiar behaviour.  I was able to reproduce it with a simple GUI and no matter how I ordered the above code (`outputAxes` before `magnetAxes`) it was always the `magnetAxes` that had the grid displayed and the other had it removed (maybe because I added the `magentAxes` widget second?).

The `grid on` statement turns the grid on for the *current axis* only so that maybe part of he confusion - the `magnetAxis` has "focus" and so it gets updated with grid while the other does not because it is never set to the current axis.

Two solutions are as follows - specify the axis that you wish to enable the grid

```
grid(handles.outputAxes,'on');  % replace grid on with this for the first axis
grid(handles.magnetAxes,'on');  % replace grid on with this for the second axis
```

or remove the `grid on` statements altogether and just do

```
set(handles.outputAxes, 'XMinorTick', 'on','XGrid','on','YGrid','on');
set(handles.magnetAxes, 'XMinorTick', 'on','XGrid','on','YGrid','on');
```

A third option is to manually set the current axis before calling the `grid on` (i.e. `axes(handles.outputAxes);`).

Comment: It's not peculiar. The [current axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) is the last axes created or clicked with the mouse.